# Completed Admin Beginner trail but now it's showing 48% complete

Tags: trailhead

A few months ago (on April 28, 2017) I completed the Admin Beginner trail in Trailhead. Soon afterwards I began the Admin Intermediate trail and got about half-way through before project schedules caused me to stop or spend little time on Trailhead.  (The last time I completed a unit was on June 30.)  Today I went back into Trailhead to pick up where I left off but found that it showed that I am only 48% of the way through my Admin Beginner trail.  Has anyone seen this happen before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this happens from time to time. The reason why is that new content is being added on a regular basis (approximately every six weeks). Reaching the end of a trail doesn't mean there won't be more of that trail later.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have seen this before. SalesForce regularly update the content of trails, and sometime add additional modules to existing trails! I often find that after a few months away from Trailhead, that when I login I need to complete additional modules to 're-complete' my trails (and thus regain the badges).

I think this is good, as SalesForce is an ever evolving platform, of course the modules content will change over time.